# Why do I have to use a group for vector animated drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-vectordrawable

I am not so sure why I have to specify a group for the animated vector as target. It seem very redudant since the object animator that is used already has a path from and a path to. Therefore, shouldn't the object animator already know how to transform the vector drawable? If so why  do I still have to set the group name as target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VectorDrawable can contain multiple paths and groups and an Animated Vector Drawable can use multiple Object Animators simultaneously to animate different parts of one VectorDrawable.

Specifying which part of the VectorDrawable you want to target with each animator is necessary to allow this sort of flexibility and scope.

For many types of attribute you would animate, think colour change or rotation, it may be impossible to guess which part of the VectorDrawable you intended to change unless you explicitly specified it.

You may say that if you are animating the pathData it should be obvious which part you are trying to change, but it doesn't really seem worth it for the Android team to try to engineer a solution to detect this when it's really an exception, better to keep it consistent.

Also there's absolutely no reason why you couldn't have a VectorDrawable with multiple lines drawn with exactly the same pathData(to look like just one line) which are then all animated separately to produce a particular effect. In this case you'd need to specify the different targets, so even with pathData you can't always infer what the intended target is.

Comment: Your answer is very clear thanks but I still have a question. Why do I need to specify a group as a target when at the beginning I already declared which drawable to act upon?

Comment: Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer. Each Object Animator doesn't usually act upon the whole Vector Drawable, just a part of it. If you have a simple Vector Drawable with only one part to it, then that might not be so obvious. It might seem like you're animating the whole 'VectorDrawable', but you're actually animating the pathData of the specific 'path' tag. You could have 5 other path tags in the same VectorDrawable if you want, that are treated differently. No special case is made, you always specify which part of the VectorDrawable you mean, even if it's a simple one with only one part.